# Changing default camera settings?

Tags: camera

Every time I add in a new camera to my scene I have to change a number of settings to fit my default (passerport opacity, composition guides, etc.). This is something of an annoyance.

Is there any way I can change the default settings so that I can just add in a camera (or any sort of object, I suppose) and have the settings be how I want them?

Comment: for that, you will have to write a script

Answer (score 1):

TLDR; create a camera with the settings you need and duplicate it when you need a new camera, so you'll have the right setting already there.

LONGER ANSWER AND PROCESS:

You can create a template .blend file where you have a set of cameras with the configuration you want to use (the same for objects).

Set this blend file as the default one (FILE > DEFAULT > SAVE STARTUP FILE). When you need to have a new camera, don't create it by scratch, but copy the one you have already in the blend file (main one, or another one hidden one in some collection you use as repository of different settings).

does it make sense to you?